# Parsing text between quotes with .NET regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have the following input text:

```
@"This is some text @foo=bar @name=""John \""The Anonymous One\"" Doe"" @age=38"
```

I would like to parse the values with the @name=value syntax as name/value pairs.  Parsing the previous string should result in the following named captures:

```
name:"foo"
value:"bar"

name:"name"
value:"John \""The Anonymous One\"" Doe"

name:"age"
value:"38"
```

I tried the following regex, which got me *almost* there:

```
@"(?:(?<=\s)|^)@(?<name>\w+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+?)\s*=\s*(?<value>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+|(?="").+?(?=(?<!\\)""))"
```

The primary issue is that it captures the opening quote in `"John \""The Anonymous One\"" Doe"`. I feel like this should be a lookbehind instead of a lookahead, but that doesn't seem to work at all.

Here are some rules for the expression:

- Name must start with a letter and can contain any letter, number, underscore, or hyphen.
- Unquoted must have at least one character and can contain any letter, number, underscore, or hyphen.
- Quoted value can contain any character including any whitespace and escaped quotes.

Edit:

Here's the result from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yK5gT1/1):

```
(?:(?<=\s)|^)@(?<name>\w+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+?)\s*=\s*(?<value>(?<!")[A-Za-z0-9_-]+|(?=").+?(?=(?<!\\)"))

(?:(?<=\s)|^) Non-capturing group
@ matches the character @ literally
(?<name>\w+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+?) Named capturing group name
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
= matches the character = literally
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?<value>(?<!")[A-Za-z0-9_-]+|(?=").+?(?=(?<!\\)")) Named capturing group value
    1st Alternative: [A-Za-z0-9_-]+
        [A-Za-z0-9_-]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
            a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
            _- a single character in the list _- literally
    2nd Alternative: (?=").+?(?=(?<!\\)")
        (?=") Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
            " matches the characters " literally
        .+? matches any character (except newline)
            Quantifier: +? Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
        (?=(?<!\\)") Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
            (?<!\\) Negative Lookbehind - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
                \\ matches the character \ literally
            " matches the characters " literally
```

Comment: Have you considered using [JSON](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/) instead?

Comment: Side note: consider if there is existing parser for whatever you are trying to parse (SQL?)... At very least re-format and annotate your regular expression so average person can reason about it (easy way is to use https://regex101.com/ and than clean up explanation a bit)...

Comment: JSON is not an option.  This is not for SQL or any existing technology which has an existing parser.  This is a very specific use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very useful .NET regex feature where multiple same-named captures are allowed. Also, there is an issue with your `(?<name>)` capture group: it allows a digit in the first position, which does not meet your 1st requirement.

So, I suggest:

```
(?si)(?:(?<=\s)|^)@(?<name>\w+[a-z0-9_-]+?)\s*=\s*(?:(?<value>[a-z0-9_-]+)|(?:"")?(?<value>.+?)(?=(?<!\\)""))
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fsi)(%3F%3A(%3F%3C%3D%5Cs)%7C%5E)%40(%3F%3Cname%3E%5Cw%2B%5Ba-z0-9_-%5D%2B%3F)%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*(%3F%3A(%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5Ba-z0-9_-%5D%2B)%7C(%3F%3A%22%22)%3F(%3F%3Cvalue%3E.%2B%3F)(%3F%3D(%3F%3C!%5C%5C)%22%22))&i=%40%22This%20is%20some%20text%20%40foo%3Dbar%20%40name%3D%22%22John%20%5C%22%22%5C%22%22%5C%22%22The%0D%0A%20Anonymous%20One%5C%22%22%20Doe%22%22%20%40age%3D38%22%0D%0A%0D%0AName%20must%20start%20with%20a%20letter%20and%20can%20contain%20any%20letter%2C%20number%2C%20underscore%2C%20or%20hyphen.%20Unquoted%20must%20have%20at%20least%20one%20character%20and%20can%20contain%20any%20letter%2C%20number%2C%20underscore%2C%20or%20hyphen.%20Quoted%20value%20can%20contain%20any%20character%20including%20any%20whitespace%20and%20escaped%20quotes.)

Note that you cannot debug .NET-specific regexes at regex101.com, you need to test them in .NET-compliant environment.

Comment: I didn't realize  you could use multiple capture groups that way.  That completely solves my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I don't understand at this point is why the last part of the expression didn't work in the original.  If I used a literal quote, it would capture the expression (including the quote, which I didn't want).  If I used a lookbehind, the expression would capture if used in isolation, but would not work when added to the full expression.  I blame my lack of knowledge of how the lookbehind functions, but I'm not really certain.  Any additional knowledge here would be useful for educational purposes.

Comment: I tend to use regex hero for a quick online test.  It's Silverlight based, so it's fairly reliable as a means of quick and dirty testing.

Comment: Regexstorm is good, too, I tested both, and I use Expresso, too.

Comment: I also fixed the name capture to look like `(?<name>[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*?)`.

Comment: Thanks all around.  You have been extremely helpful.

Comment: From what I can see `(?=").+?` is not what you wanted because the positive *look-ahead* was checking if we have a `"` right after a `=` or `= `. So, it was tested for, and then captured. A look-behind `(?<=")` would also just check if there is a `"` before the first character after the equal sign, and then it does not match. Removing the look-around just forces the `"` to be consumed.

Comment: I just want to note that I am using inline flags `(?si)` to force ignorecase and singleline modes. You can use `RegexOptions.Singleline` and `RegexOptions.Ignorecase` if you do not want to use those inline options.

Answer (score 0):

Use string methods.

**Split**

```
string myLongString = ""@"This is some text @foo=bar @name=""John \""The Anonymous One\"" Doe"" @age=38"

string[] nameValues = myLongString.Split('@');
```

From there either use Split function with "=" or use **IndexOf("=")**.